# Computation of the minimal polynomial of a matrix in Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematica

On the wolfram website, the following program is given for computing the minimal polynomial of a square matrix $a$ in the variable $x$:

> MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_List?MatrixQ,x_]:=Module[
>
> {
>
> ```
> i,
> n=1,
> qu={},
> mnm={Flatten[IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]]}
> ```
>
> },
>
> While[Length[qu]==0,
>
> ```
> AppendTo[mnm,Flatten[MatrixPower[a,n]]];
> qu=NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]];
> n++
> ```
>
> ];
>
> First[qu].Table[x^i,{i,0,n-1}]
>
> ]

(It's given here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html also)

I'm having trouble following the algrothim it's using. How is Mathematica actually computing the matrix minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't quite grok the code, it looks like M. is building in increasingly long list of powers of $a$, and searching (by NullSpace) for a relation of linear dependency. Once one is found, the coefficients of the dependency relation are turned into a polynomial through the Table method.

Comment: Ooh ok. That's specific enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This guide is for the user who is not familar with mathematica.

Step 1. 
Implement the following code.

```
  MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_List?MatrixQ,x_]:=Module[
    {
      i,
      n=1,
      qu={},
      mnm={Flatten[IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]]}
    },
    While[Length[qu]==0,
      AppendTo[mnm,Flatten[MatrixPower[a,n]]];
      qu=NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]];
      n++
    ];
    First[qu].Table[x^i,{i,0,n-1}]
  ]
```

Step 2.
Declare the matrix $a$.
For example, 
$a=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$;

Step 3.
Then implement

```
Factor[MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a, x]]
```

Comment: How is a user not familiar with Mathematica going to even understand what steps 1 and 3 are about?

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there some way to permanently save the function "MatrixMinimalPolynomial." Also in advance if you see this in 2018.

Comment: @Elliot Sorry. I don't understand what you mean "permanently save"? Do you mean is there a way to "save" the module. Then you don't need to load the module before running the command MatrixMinimalPolynomial every time?
Maybe you can save it as a package. Then set Mathematica load the package automatically when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is now five years old, but it still came up when I searched so I'll post incase others see.

One quick workaround is to just use the Jordan normal form. Simply Set your matrix A (using $A:=\{\{\},\ldots \{\}\}$), and then enter JordanDecomposition[A]. This returns two matrices $M,N$. The second is the matrix in Jordan normal form, and the first gives you the similarity $A=MNM^{-1}$.

The minimal polynomial has a factor of $(x-\lambda)^n$ for each $\lambda$ appearing on the diagonal, and $n$ is the size of the largest $\lambda$-[Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix).

For example, the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7
\end{bmatrix} $$
was the minimal polyonmial
$$(x+2)^3(x-3)^2(x-7).$$
It also has the characteristic polynomial $$(x+2)^3(x-3)^2(x-7).$$

Comment: Instead of $n$ being the number of Jordan blocks, it should be the size of the largest block instead...?

Comment: @user202729 thanks.